# What is Apache's equivalent of Nginx's try_files?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx

In Nginx there is [`try_files`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files), a config directive that "checks for the existence of files in order, and returns the first file that is found". I find it very neat to do this

```
location ~* \.(gif|jpe?g|css|js)$ {
    try_files $uri 404;
}
```

which is a safe way of directly serving static files, without bothering the web frameworks. How can I do the same thing in Apache?

Comment: What was the solution you went for? The selected answer does not really meet my use case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I commonly see this done with mod_rewrite:

```
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ balancer://app_cluster%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]
```

It means "If a file does not exist on the file system, then proxy it through my mod_proxy_balancer cluster." Otherwise, if the file exists on the file system, it is simply served up by Apache relative to the defined `DocumentRoot` in your virtualhost.

But that's not my favorite way, mostly because it would require a `stat` system call per request.

With mod_proxy, you can use `ProxyPassMatch` if you have a new enough version of Apache ([see documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassmatch)). Such as:

`ProxyPassMatch \.(gif|jpe?g|css|js)$ !`

Which uses the ! to indicate Apache should *not* proxy requests matching that regular expression.

If you are using an older version of Apache, you will have the `ProxyPass` directive available to you, but it only matches URI prefixes (this is my current preferred method):

```
ProxyPass /images !
ProxyPass /stylesheets !
```

Of course, if you must do regular expression matching as you mentioned above, then you can simply modify the mod_rewrite rule I posted at the top to negate a match against the `%{REQUEST_URI}`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I think the "bad" way is more similar to `try_files`, because it checks for the existence of the file. There doesn't seem to be a way to do it for `ProxyPass` though.