# Gitlab and Apache - Uploaded images 404 errors

Tags: apache-2.4, gitlab

I've installed Gitlab on my LAMP server and it's worked well until I decided to add a project avatar today.

The images upload as expected to `/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/uploads/projects/1/projectlogo.png` but when I reloaded the page the image didn't load.

Browsing directly to the image url `http://gitlab.myserver.com:8080/uploads/project/avatar/2/projectlogo.png` gives me a 404 error.

I've been searching all over and trying various things between adding a ProxyPass for /uploads to the Gitlab apache conf file. Changing the ownership of the uploads directory. I even attempted to modify production.rb so that Gitlab would be responsible for serving static files `config.serve_static_files = true`

Here is the apache config file I'm using at the moment.

```
# This configuration has been tested on GitLab 8.2
# Note this config assumes unicorn is listening on default port 8080 and
# gitlab-workhorse is listening on port 8181. To allow gitlab-workhorse to
# listen on port 8181, edit or create /etc/default/gitlab and change or add the following:
#
# gitlab_workhorse_options="-listenUmask 0 -listenNetwork tcp -listenAddr 127.0.0.1:8181 -authBackend http://127.0.0.1:8080"
#
#Module dependencies
# mod_rewrite
# mod_proxy
# mod_proxy_http
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName gitlab.myserver.com
  ServerSignature Off

  ProxyPreserveHost On

  # Ensure that encoded slashes are not decoded but left in their encoded state.
  # http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#get-single-project
  AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

  <Location />
    # New authorization commands for apache 2.4 and up
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#access
    Require all granted

    #Allow forwarding to gitlab-workhorse
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8181
    #Allow forwarding to GitLab Rails app (Unicorn)
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080
    ProxyPassReverse http://gitlab.myserver.com/
  </Location>

  # Apache equivalent of nginx try files
  # http://serverfault.com/questions/290784/what-is-apaches-equivalent-of-nginxs-try-files
  # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954516/apache2-proxypass-for-rails-app-gitlab
  RewriteEngine on

  #Forward these requests to gitlab-workhorse
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[\w\.-]+/[\w\.-]+/gitlab-lfs/objects.* [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[\w\.-]+/[\w\.-]+/builds/download.* [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[\w\.-]+/[\w\.-]+/repository/archive.* [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/v3/projects/.*/repository/archive.* [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/ci/api/v1/builds/[0-9]+/artifacts.* [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[\w\.-]+/[\w\.-]+/(info/refs|git-upload-pack|git-receive-pack)$
  RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8181%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,NE]

  #Forward any other requests to GitLab Rails app (Unicorn)
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uploads
  RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,NE]

  # needed for downloading attachments
  DocumentRoot /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public

  #Set up apache error documents, if back end goes down (i.e. 503 error) then a maintenance/deploy page is thrown up.
  ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
  ErrorDocument 422 /422.html
  ErrorDocument 500 /500.html
  ErrorDocument 503 /deploy.html

  # It is assumed that the log directory is in /var/log/httpd.
  # For Debian distributions you might want to change this to
  # /var/log/apache2.
  LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common_forwarded
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/gitlab.pyramidmines.com_error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/gitlab.pyramidmines.com_forwarded.log common_forwarded
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/gitlab.pyramidmines.com_access.log combined env=!dontlog
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/gitlab.pyramidmines.com.log combined

  ProxyPass /uploads !
  <Directory /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/uploads>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Which is mostly from the recipe for apache2.4, with changes to the log directory, document root and the proxy pass for uploads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After bashing my head against the keyboard for a few days I noticed the port number attached to the external_url entry in /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb

`external_url 'http://gitlab.myserver.com:8080'`

Removing the port number solved my image 404 issues.

`external_url 'http://gitlab.myserver.com'`

Comment: had the same problem with gitlab being reachable over a DNS Alias (CName). the file upload only worked with the adress provided in the gitlab configs.