# After upgradeing gitlab - GUI / Inteface broken - not working correctly

Tags: ubuntu, web, upgrade, gitlab, graphical-user-interface

we have a big problem. Since we updated gitlab from version 8.11.7-ce.0 to 8.12.1-ce.0 our webgui is broken:
[gitlab - broken gui view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peEhf.png)

we currently don't know why this happened.

we are using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Does someone have the same issue or an idea to fix this problem?

EDIT 1:

I checked my log files:

```
Started GET "/assets/application-891a61baf08dd362204cccb62419682e810754e7b9e657eb3d33897e53d5bd96.css" for 80.149.35.188 at 2016-09-26 12:26:12 +0200
Processing by ProjectsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"namespace_id"=>"assets", "id"=>"application-891a61baf08dd362204cccb62419682e810754e7b9e657eb3d33897e53d5bd96.css"}
Filter chain halted as :project rendered or redirected
```

and checked this one 404 file and the file exists. I really don't get it why we are getting an 404 error.

EDIT 2 - **solution**:
we have fixed our problem. The problem was that our apache vhost proxy configuration was wrong.

now this looks like:

```
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  # Ensure that encoded slashes are not decoded but left in their encoded state.
  # http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#get-single-project
  AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

  <Location />
    # New authorization commands for apache 2.4 and up
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#access
    Require all granted

    #Allow forwarding to gitlab-workhorse
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8282
    ProxyPassReverse https://xxx/
  </Location>

  # Apache equivalent of nginx try files
  # http://serverfault.com/questions/290784/what-is-apaches-equivalent-of-nginxs-try-files
  # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954516/apache2-proxypass-for-rails-app-gitlab
  RewriteEngine on

  #Don't escape encoded characters in api requests
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/v3/.*
  RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8282%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,NE]

  #Forward all requests to gitlab-workhorse except existing files like error documents
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uploads/.*
  RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8282%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA]

  RequestHeader set X_FORWARDED_PROTO 'https'
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Ssl on
```

Comment: May I ask what you changed? I have the same issue but even after changing the vhost gitlab is still broken.
edit: found out in my case it was because of a wrong DocumentRoot

Answer (score 0):

Your static resources location has changed and your web server configuration hasn't been changed accordingly.

You need to study your web server `error.log` and see what resources are returning `404` HTTP status code and then find where those resources are located. Then you can fix your server configuration.

Comment: I didn't change the location of my resources. I just updated gitlab. But if you mean that gitlab changed my resource location after this update..

But I checked my logs and find an 404 error.

Started GET "/assets/application-891a61baf08dd362204cccb62419682e810754e7b9e657eb3d33897e53d5bd96.css" 
Filter chain halted as :project rendered or redirected

and checked this one 404 file and the file exists. I really don't get it why we are getting an 404 error.

Comment: Please add the log entry to the question with proper formatting, as it is unclear which part is from the log and which part is your text.